# How to allocate meshes that may go out of range and thus not need rendering?

Tags: game-engine, mesh

I'm writing my own game and game engine. One thing that I'm getting confused on is I'm not sure what to do when I draw nearby players. There could be 0 players nearby or multiple. Should I dynamically allocate mesh instances as players walk in range and delete them as players walk out of range or should I use static allocation and keep a resource pool of mesh instances to be used as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coding some MMORPG with a lot of characters you might destroy your meshes if you haven't seen the corresponding actor for a while, but in a 12 player FPS just keep them in memory at all times; no use re-constructing them and re-uploading data to the graphics card.

Prior to rendering, just decide whether or not to render each mesh (or world 'chunk'). Common culling operations are (in order):

- Distance culling: if the mesh/actor is > X distance from the camera, cull it
- View frustrum culling: if the mesh/actor is outside the viewing volume, cull it
- Occlusion culling (optional, I suppose): culls meshes/actors behind solid geometry. This is pretty advanced I'd say.